# How to make custom url prefix in django

Tags: python, django, url, prefixes

Have a little problem, tried to google it, but get nothing.
What I need:
Configure a URL for app in Django, like this:

```
/myproject/myapp/models.py
class MyApp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ....

/myproject/myapp/views.py
def make_something_with_app(app_id):
    # will make smthing cool
```

Let's think, my site has a `"example.com"` address, and we have two objects in DB from `MyApp model - app1(id=0), app2(id=1)`.
So, what I need?
When we go to the `app1.example.com`, we call `make_something_with_app(0)`, and when we go to the `app2.example.co`m, we call `make_something_with_app(1)`

Is there a way to make it? Thanks.

Comment: You want to to run this models from different host names? Or You will use one host name and want to run this models?

Comment: I`m not see here any problem.

Comment: I want to use one host name, and run different models with prefixes. @Sayse link me to the multi-tenancy link, I think that's what I need, I'll try django-tenant-schemas and the will close this question, if everything ok.

Comment: You want to use single url for 2 views? For Why?

Comment: Nope, I want few urls to 1 views.
For example, when we ask for app1.example.com, we get our index view with app1 parameters, and for app2.example.com we get index with app2 parameters

Comment: You question is marked as duplicate, and i can`t to write a script for example.